# Ruby request passing wrong parameter to object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

OK, I have a basic Ruby question that I can not find an answer to here.  I have an web app that tracks users who post essentially advertisements called listings.  I have an index of all listing titles across all users.  Each user has many listings.

So in the index of listings I have the following code

```
 <%= link_to listing.title, listing %>
```

listing goes to a page which contains both user contact information and the detailed advertisement. My problem is that when it goes to that page it is trying to pass listing.id to user.id instead of passing the `user_id` from the listing object.

The controller method for showing the detailed advertisement is the following two lines.

```
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
```

The error I am getting is Couldn't find User with 'id' = 45 when I follow the link `localhost:3000/listings/45`.  I do not have 45 users but do have more than 45 listings.  I am confused on how to get the foreign key to pass correctly in this case.

I am running **Ruby 2.1.3** with rails **4.2.0.beta2**

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to find a `User` and `Listing` using the same `id`, while you only receive the `id` for a `Listing` in your `ListingController`.

Assuming that you have your relationships setup in the two models, the way to get the correct `Listing` and `User` is:

```
@listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
@user = @listing.user
```

Comment: Hi.  Yes I do have the relationship set up.  Listing depends on user and user has many listings.  That solved it so thank you very much.